# Why are my GA4 UI total users not adding up with the ones in the BigQuery export?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I am trying to recreate the Google analytics 4 data in BigQuery for reporting. I’m trying to count total users by using the following query

```
SELECT
count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as total_users
FROM `project.dataset.events_*`
WHERE _table_suffix = “20221201”
```

Problem is that for any given day, I get around 10-15% LESS total users than I see in the GA4 interface. Why can this be?

I tried Googleing but it didn’t make me any wiser. Anyone has had the same problem?

Comment: Are you matching Explorer or pre-generated reports?

Comment: @BNazaruk This is the nested raw data coming from the BigQuery GA4 export, on event level.

Comment: That part I know. I'm asking what you're comparing it to.